# How to make subsequent calls using rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

At three places I am making API calls (I have numbered it (1),(2),(3)).

```js
getCMPortsMapping(siteRef: string) {

  Object.keys(cmBoardPortsEnum).forEach(port => {

    let queryParams = "output and system and enabled and config and " + cmBoardPortsEnum[port];

    let cmBoardPortsMappings = new CMBoardPortsMappings("", "", false, "", "");
    // ------- (1) --------
    this.siteService.getDetailsBySiteRef(queryParams, siteRef).subscribe(portsDetail => {
      if (portsDetail && portsDetail.rows.length > 0) {
        cmBoardPortsMappings.type = cmBoardPortsEnum[port];

        //Check if port is enabled ------ (2) --------
        this.siteService.getWritablePointData(this.helperService.parseRef(portsDetail.rows[0].id)).subscribe(portEnable => {
          if (portEnable && portEnable.rows.length) {
            //got data for port
            if (portEnable.rows[0] && portEnable.rows[0].val) {
              //got port enable/disbale
              let val = this.helperService.TypeMapping(portEnable.rows[0].val)
              switch (val) {
                case "1.0":
                  cmBoardPortsMappings.isEnabled = true;
                  //Get the port mapping
                  let mappingQuery = "system and cmd and " + cmBoardPortsEnum[port];
                  // ----------- (3) -----------
                  this.siteService.getDetailsBySiteRef(mappingQuery, siteRef).subscribe(mappingDetails => {
                    if (mappingDetails && mappingDetails.rows.length) {
                      mappingDetails.rows[0].dis.split("SystemEquip-")[1] != "" ? cmBoardPortsMappings.mapping = mappingDetails.rows[0].dis.split("SystemEquip-")[1] : '';
                      this.helperService.parseRef(mappingDetails.rows[0].id) != "" ? cmBoardPortsMappings.ref = this.helperService.parseRef(mappingDetails.rows[0].id) : '';

                      if (cmBoardPortsMappings.mapping != "") {
                        cmBoardPortsMappings.param = cmBoardPortsMappings.mapping.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "")
                      }
                    }
                    else {
                      throw new Error("In correct port mapping read from haystack")
                    }
                  });
                  break;
                case "0.0":
                  cmBoardPortsMappings.isEnabled = false;
                  cmBoardPortsMappings.mapping = "";
                  break;
                default:
                  throw new Error("In correct port val read from haystack")
              }
              this.cmBoardPortsMappingsCollection.set(cmBoardPortsEnum[port], cmBoardPortsMappings);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I had used switchmap in some other piece of code as well

```js
this.siteService.getFloorRooms(this.floorRef).pipe(
  switchMap(res => {
    const rest = res
    let elementId = [];
    res.rows.forEach((element) => {
      elementId.push(element.id)
    });
    for (const color of elementId) {
      this.roomref = (color).split(":")[1].split(" ")[0];
    }
    return this.siteService.checkPairedRooms(this.roomref)
  })
).subscribe(m => {
  this.rooms = m.rows;
  if (m.rows.length == 1) {
    this.paired = true;
  }
  this.getExistingFloorPlan();
});
```

Should I use `mergemap`, `concatmap`, `switchmap`? What is the correct way to implement it? As pointed out by someone foreach inside switchmap will not return , so using `forkjoin` and other utilities would help but I haven't used these rxjs utility functions.

Comment: @Alexander Staroselsky , now would you be able to help me out

Comment: @munna munim any help on this please

Comment: Are `this.siteService.getDetailsBySiteRef`, `this.siteService.getWritablePointData` and `this.siteService.getFloorRooms` http requests? Or how often do they emit?

Comment: @fridoo Yeah they are http requests, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether you use `mergemap`, `concatmap`, `switchmap` with http requests, because they only emit once and complete.

Create an array of concatenated http requests mapping each request to the next one and the final one to your desired output. Then pass that array to `forkJoin`. Enjoy.

```js
getCMPortsMapping(siteRef: string) {
  forkJoin(Object.keys(cmBoardPortsEnum).map(port => {
    let queryParams = "output and system and enabled and config and " + cmBoardPortsEnum[port];
    return this.siteService.getDetailsBySiteRef(queryParams, siteRef).pipe(
      filter(portsDetail => portsDetail && portsDetail.rows.length > 0),
      switchMap(portsDetail => this.siteService.getWritablePointData(this.helperService.parseRef(portsDetail.rows[0].id))),
      filter(portEnable => portEnable && portEnable.rows.length && portEnable.rows[0] && portEnable.rows[0].val),
      switchMap(portEnable => {
        const cmBoardPortsMappings = new CMBoardPortsMappings("", "", false, "", "");
        cmBoardPortsMappings.type = cmBoardPortsEnum[port];
        const val = this.helperService.TypeMapping(portEnable.rows[0].val)
        switch (val) {
          case "1.0":
            cmBoardPortsMappings.isEnabled = true;
            return enrichCmBoardPortsMappings(cmBoardPortsMappings, siteRef);
          case "0.0":
            cmBoardPortsMappings.isEnabled = false;
            cmBoardPortsMappings.mapping = "";
            return of(cmBoardPortsMappings);
          default:
            return throwError('In correct port val read from haystack');
        }
      })
    )
  })).subscribe(cmBoardPortsMappingsArray => cmBoardPortsMappingsArray.forEach(cmBoardPortsMappings =>
    this.cmBoardPortsMappingsCollection.set(cmBoardPortsMappings.type, cmBoardPortsMappings)
  ));
}

enrichCmBoardPortsMappings(cmBoardPortsMappings: CMBoardPortsMappings, siteRef: string): Observable<CMBoardPortsMappings> {
  let mappingQuery = "system and cmd and " + cmBoardPortsMappings.type;
  return this.siteService.getDetailsBySiteRef(mappingQuery, siteRef).pipe(
    tap(mappingDetails => { 
      if(!(mappingDetails && mappingDetails.rows.length)) throw new Error('In correct port mapping read from haystack') ;
    }),
    map(mappingDetails => {
      if (mappingDetails.rows[0].dis.split("SystemEquip-")[1] != "") {
        cmBoardPortsMappings.mapping = mappingDetails.rows[0].dis.split("SystemEquip-")[1];
      }
      if (this.helperService.parseRef(mappingDetails.rows[0].id) != "") {
        cmBoardPortsMappings.ref = this.helperService.parseRef(mappingDetails.rows[0].id);
      }
      if (cmBoardPortsMappings.mapping != "") {
        cmBoardPortsMappings.param = cmBoardPortsMappings.mapping.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "")
      }
      return cmBoardPortsMappings;
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer ,I really apreciate , for this I'll have to use npm package, isn't this throw-if available in rxjs itself

Comment: negative points for using a basically non existent and not needed library dependency

Comment: @fridoo if you could explain why we use "switchMap(portEnable => { " the second switchmap , thanks !

Comment: @Enthu Because you want to execute `this.siteService.getDetailsBySiteRef` in certain circumstances. You have to use `switchMap` so that this Observable ends up in the chain and gets subscribed to.